# Unable to replace package in azure Artifact

Tags: azure-devops

I have uploaded a package(com.test:project0.1) in azure devops Artifact, however when I am making changes in code, the pipeline is getting successful but unable to replace the old package.

Can anyone please assist me.

Answer (score 0):

If you used another nuget package to replace the old one, also, you have set the same version as the old before, then you should remove the old nuget caches first to remove the old one.

You should check the option **Disable Local Cache** option.

[image]

Then, re-run to check that.

**Also**, if you push a version number for the nuget package, you should modify the nugrt version under `csproj` file to the new one.

Comment: Hi Perry Qian-MSFT, Do you mean i have to upload the packages every time with new version only. Sorry but I am using maven packages and not the nuget package, i do not see disable local cache in it